# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

kafka: kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1

scala:2.12

```
val TOPIC_EVENT_XXX = "EVENT.xxx.ALL"
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.bean(classOf[Event]).schema
val allEventsDF = spark
                  .readStream
                  .format("kafka")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Streaming01.simon.com:9090,Streaming02.simon.com:9090,Streaming03.simon.com:9090,Streaming04.simon.com:9090")
                  .option("subscribe", TOPIC_EVENT_XXX)
                  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")  
                  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 5000)//old,1000000
                  .load()
                  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value")) 
                  .selectExpr("parsed_value.*")
```

```
val KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "Streaming01.simon.com:9090,Streaming02.simon.com:9090,Streaming03.simon.com:9090,Streaming04.simon.com:9090,Ingest01.simon.com:9090,Ingest02.simon.com:9090,Notify01.simon.com:9090,Notify02.simon.com:9090,Serving01.simon.com:9090,Serving02.simon.com:9090,"

var waybillStatesKafkaSinkQuery = waybillStates.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
            .writeStream
            .outputMode("append")
            .format("kafka")        // can be "orc", "json", "csv",memory,console etc.
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
            .option("topic", TOPIC_TIMECHAIN_WAYBILL)  //TIMECHAIN.WAYBILL.ALL //TIMECHAIN.WAYBILL.TL   //TOPIC_TIMECHAIN_WAYBILL
            .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_PATH_TL_EVENT_WAYBILL_STATES)
            .option("kafka.max.request.size", "164217728")//134217728//209715200
            .option("kafka.buffer.memory", "164217728")
            .option("kafka.timeout.ms",180000)
            .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms",180000)
            .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms",180000)
            .option("kafka.heartbeat.interval.ms",120000)
            .option("kafka.retries",100)
            .option("failOnDataLoss","false")//后添加的【2018-07-11】
            .start()
```

The following error occurred while running the above program.：

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.